# Bad Gateway 502 on Mobile Phone

Tags: pusher

When using Pusher over mobile internet we're getting these error messages while it tries to connect through the ws:// protocol. After failing it connects successfully through wss://.

What can I do?

Comment: No comments for why I was downvoted, this was a real problem and below is the real and only solution after spending hours on this problem. I couldn't find this problem/solution anywhere, so I thought I'd document it. Perhaps someone out there found a different solution? Doesn't appear so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purchase the encrypted plan, and tell the client to connect "Encrypted: true" and all your troubles will disappear!